# Send nested list to a controller in .NET 8

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I'm using fetch to send data via POST to WebApplication controllers with this general function.

```
var postRequest = async (url, objeto) => {
    try {
        DATA = JSON.stringify(objeto);
        const respuesta = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: DATA,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        if (!respuesta.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Error en la solicitud: ${respuesta.status} - ${respuesta.statusText}`);
        }

        const response = await respuesta.json();
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al realizar la solicitud POST:', error);
        throw error;
    }
```

My goal is send "IdentificadorSesion", "Preguntas" atributes from this model.

```
using Aplicacion.DTOs;
using Dominio.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace WebApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ClientesVM
    {
        public ClientesVM()
        {
            DDLTiposRespuesta = new SelectList(new List<string>());
            DDLTiposDocumento = new SelectList(new List<string>());
        }

        public string IdentificadorSesion { get; set; }
        public string TipoDocumento { get; set; }
        public string NumeroDocumento { get; set; }
        public string NombreCompleto { get; set; }
        public string TipoBusqueda { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
        public int Dia { get; set; }
        public int Mes { get; set; }
        public int Anio { get; set; }

        public WebApp.ViewModels.NegPreguntaDTO Preguntas { get; set; }
        public SelectList DDLTiposRespuesta { get; set; }
        public SelectList DDLTiposDocumento { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApp.ViewModels
{
    public class NegPreguntaDTO
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string? Respuesta { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So in order to do that I using `postRequest` like this

```
let preguntasRespondidas = [];
$('#FRMResponderPreguntas select').each(function (index, element) {
    let pregunta = {
        Id: index + 1,
        Respuesta: $(element).find('option:selected').val() || 'default_value'
    };
    preguntasRespondidas.push(pregunta);
});


let url = '@Url.Action("GetHTMLVerificacion", "Clientes")';
let data = {
    'IdentificadorSesion': sesionVerificacion,
    'Preguntas': preguntasRespondidas
};

const response = await postRequest(url, data);
```

An example of the petition payload generated by this function is

```
{
   "IdentificadorSesion":"cd20e10f-55f3-4bfd-a338-eb74fffafed3",
   "Preguntas":[
      {
         "Id":1,
         "Respuesta":"Ricardo Martínez López"
      },
      {
         "Id":2,
         "Respuesta":"6"
      },
      {
         "Id":3,
         "Respuesta":"Laura López Hernández"
      }
   ]
}
```

But data comes null to the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetHTMLVerificacion([FromBody] ClientesVM vm)
{

    var success = true;
    try{}
    catch (Exception ex){}

    return Json(new { success });

}
```

I have been testing and at least it works if I don't send `preguntas` attribute in the petition body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {"IdentificadorSesion":"cd20e10f-55f3-4bfd-a338-eb74fffafed3","Preguntas":[{"Id":1,"Respuesta":"Ricardo Martínez López"},{"Id":2,"Respuesta":"6"},{"Id":3,"Respuesta":"Laura López Hernández"}]}

The payload example you have shared has `Preguntas` as an array of objects but the property named `Preguntas` in the model class `ClientesVM` is not an array. You should make it an array type for the model binding to work.

```
public class ClientesVM
{
    .
    .
    .
    public WebApp.ViewModels.NegPreguntaDTO[] Preguntas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It works!. Thank you!. I just don't get it why it works in .NET Framework but not in .NET Core because I never had to make it array before.